# Can the function called in event listener access its parent values?

Tags: javascript

I am confused by the behavior of callback function inside event listener.
It works.

```js
function main(){
const value="lorem"
document.addEventListener("click",()=>{
console.log("clicked")
console.log(value)
})
}

main()
```

But this doesn't works. The error thrown is `Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined`

```js
function handleClick(){
console.log("clicked")
console.log(value)
}
function main(){
const value="lorem"
document.addEventListener("click",handleClick)
}
main()
```

This also doesn't work.

```js
function handleClick(){
console.log("clicked")
console.log(value)//but this doesn't
}
function main(){
const value="lorem"
document.addEventListener("click",function(){
  console.log(value)//this works 
  handleClick()
})
}
main()
```

In the latest case , how can I access `value` inside the inline callback function but not inside handleClick function called by the inline callback function ?
So how can I access `value` inside callback `handleClick`? Except doing this:

```js
function handleClick(value){
console.log("clicked")
console.log(value)//now it works
}
function main(){
const value="lorem"
document.addEventListener("click",function(){
  console.log(value)//this works 
  handleClick(value)
})
}
main()
```

Comment: If `value` is declared inside a function, then its scope is limited to the body of that function. Code outside that function cannot directly access `value`. You could pass `value` as an argument to the other function like you have done in the last code example.

Comment: @Yousaf so even if I add event listener inside a function the callback function cannot access the variables declared inside the function. Is it that?

Comment: If the callback function is defined _inside_ function that contains the variable declaration, then the callback can access that variable; otherwise, it can't.

Comment: Oh nice point @Yousaf . Many Many thanks .